# is there any reason not to install a second instance of MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I already have mongoDB on my mac (OS mavericks) because it comes packaged with Meteor.  I'm learning some pure, non-Meteor node.js right now.  I'd like to work with mongoDB, but I'm afraid to change any of the configuration I've already got on my machine, as I don't want to screw up the Mongo that comes packaged with Meteor.

Is this something I should be concerned about?  How do I protect my other mongo instance?

Comment: Can u please clearify what do u want to asking??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by the MongoDB that comes with Meteor you mean the MongoDB database Meteor uses internally when you type "meteor" and that resides in .meteor inside your app folder. In that case it's no problem adding a MongoDB installation to the OS, they won't conflict.

In fact, I recommend to separately install MongoDB for different reasons. When you are running a production app it's easier to scale, let multiple apps use the same database etc.

First install MongoDB, for example with Homebrew. Then you just run your app with

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1/<db> meteor
```

Answer (score 0):

According to mongodb's documentation:

[...In many cases running multiple instances of mongod on a single system **is not recommended** but for testing purposes of course possible](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/configuration/#run-multiple-database-instances-on-the-same-system).

I don't think that meteor has done intensive configuration changes to mongodb's out-of-the-box configuration (except of course if you've done already configuration amendments for special sharding, Oplog tailing strategies etc.)